# How can I convert '?' to NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset and there are missing values which are encoded as `?`. My problem is how can I change the missing values, `?`, to `NaN`? So I can drop any row with `NaN`. Can I just use `.replace()` ?

Comment: How is your dataset stored in memory ?

Comment: It's string, sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replace`:

```
 df = df.replace('?', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also read the data initially by passing 
`df = pd.read_csv('filename',na_values = '?')`
It will automatically replace '?' to NaN

Comment: This is great. I forgot that there is already a parameter dealing with na_values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop the row which contain '?', you do not need to change `'?'` to `'NaN'`

```
df[(df=='?').sum(1)==0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this,

> df[df == '?'] = np.nan